# How can i push files in sdcard - android

Tags: android, android-emulator, sd-card, android-sdcard, android-sdk-2.3

`adb remount` I get the following error `device not found`.

I am trying to create a folder and push multiple files on sdcard. When I try to use the command I have already created sdcard for my emulator.

I am using android with eclipse.

Anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: start by connecting your device, and then list the devices using 'adb devices'

Comment: Have you started the emulator before you tried the command? You could also use the file explorer view in Eclipse after the emulator started.

Comment: i did this it shows List of devices attached but there is no list

Comment: @WarrenFaith i am doing this now

Answer (score 1):

Here is the tutorial about push files on SD Card

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/03/24/how-to-add-files-like-images-inside-your-emulator-in-android/